# Eclipse outline view and Spring Roo

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo

When using spring-roo within STS I do not see AspectJ generated functions in the outline view.
Is this possible at all?

Update: it seams that this is an issue with my STS installation or with my project since this feature is working at a colleages machine. So I have to find out why it is not working on my machine (current STS installed, Java 7).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Find a triangle in the top right of the package explorer, click it and a contextual menu will appear. Select "Filters..." and you'll see a window that allows you to select filters for Java elements.

Find in the central pane the option **"Hide generated Spring Roo ITDs"**

The next time the selection will appear directly under the triangle, so you can switch the filter faster.

Comment: This shows the ITDs in the package explorer, so for one entity I have typically 1 java file and around 6 *.aj files. What I would like is to open the entity class (the java file) and see the complete class with all generated functions in the outline view.

Answer (score 1):

In new versions: Project Explore > Working Set Menu (triangle in the top right of the package explorer) -> Customize View , find for "Hide generated Spring Roo ITDs" unselect it.

good luck